# Nebular Time Picker throwing 'nb-timepicker' is not a known element?

Tags: angular, nebular

I'm trying to implement nebular TimePicker component in my Angular 8 project, and I followed the Nebular Documentation mentioned here:

https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/timepicker

But they didn't mention How can I import timepicker module into my project?, I tried this

```
import 'NbTimepickerModule' from '@nebular/theme';
```

but this error raised:

> Module "../../node_modules/@nebular/theme" has no exported member
> ‘NbTimepickerModule’. Did you mean ‘NbDatepickerModule’?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe your theme library is the old version. Update the package to the latest version.6.2.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timepicker is not part of all nebular version.

[Nebular Changelog](https://github.com/akveo/nebular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

Timepicker is only available on v6.1+.

#### Extra

Your imports should look like this

```js
//app.module
import { NbTimepickerModule } from '@nebular/theme';
...
imports: [
  ...
  NbTimepickerModule.forRoot(),
],
...
```

```js
//your submodule.module
import { NbTimepickerModule } from '@nebular/theme';
...
imports: [
  ...
  NbTimepickerModule;
],
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The datetime-picker wasn't available in nebular 6.0.0. I updated to 7.0.0 and everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

First you must import it in your module :

```
import {NbTimepickerModule } from "@nebular/theme";
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // ...
    NbTimepickerModule,
  ],
})
```

Second add the NbTimepickerModule.forRoot() to your module too :

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // ...
    NbTimepickerModule.forRoot(),
  ],
})
```

for more details this is the link you need :
https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/timepicker/overview#nbtimepickerdirective

Comment: this error raised, `@nebular/theme has no exported member ‘NbTimepickerModule’. Did you mean ‘NbDatepickerModule’?`, did you import Nebular using NPM?

Comment: you must first install nebular theme in your json package see this  [link](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/guides/install-nebular#using-angular-cli)    then you can import the `NbTimepickerModule` in your `app.module.ts`, i meant `NbTimepickerModule` not `NbDatepickerModule`, time picker is for only time like 01:02:01 , NbDatepickerModule is for date

Comment: I've imported and downloaded the theme and I can use all it's components except `NbTimepickerModule`, and I know that you mean `NbTimepickerModule not NbDatepickerModule`, in my previous comment I sent you the error occurred when import the NbTimepickerModule.

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding, look if you have more then one module in your app import the nbdatetimepicker  in your app.module.ts and don't forget .forRoot(), if you import your nbtimepicker in your specefic module without app.module.ts it will not recognize it

Comment: I've the same problem, on `app.module` I've `NbTimepickerModule.forRoot()` and in the module where the component is declared I've `NbTimepickerModule`. And nothing, stop execution and nothing, eveything else is working. Is something weird, I stop the `ng serve`, and run it again ( just in case, and nothing). In fact `vscode` don't show me any error but `ng serve` does